# OpenCV slowdown

Tags: c++, linux, performance, opencv

I have recently experimented with OpenCV and Python on Linux (Debian testing, kernel 5.6.0, OpenCV 4.2.0). I noticed a slowdown of my application, so I wrote a minimal example in C++ which I am showing below. The program exhibits the same slowdown:

```
#include <chrono>
#include <iostream>    
#include <opencv2/core.hpp>
#include <opencv2/highgui.hpp>

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{    
    cv::VideoCapture cap{0};
    cap.set(cv::CAP_PROP_FRAME_WIDTH, 320);
    cap.set(cv::CAP_PROP_FRAME_HEIGHT, 240);
    cap.set(cv::CAP_PROP_FPS, 60);
    cv::Mat src;
    cap >> src;

    auto lastTime = std::chrono::system_clock::now();
    int count = 0;
    while (cap.read(src)) {
        cv::imshow("src", src);
        if (cv::waitKey(1) >= 0) {
            break;
        }
        if (++count >= 10) {
            auto currentTime = std::chrono::system_clock::now();
            auto delta = currentTime - lastTime;
            std::cout << "FPS: "
                  << (10000000 / std::chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::microseconds>(delta).count())
                  << std::endl;
            lastTime = currentTime;
            count = 0;
        }
    }
    
    cap.release();
    cv::destroyAllWindows();
}
```

Compile with:

```
g++ -Wall -O3 -I/usr/include/opencv4 x.cpp -o x -lopencv_core -lopencv_videoio -lopencv_highgui
```

The slowdown is very noticable and fast:

```
FPS: 19
FPS: 23
FPS: 23
FPS: 20
FPS: 16
FPS: 14
FPS: 13
FPS: 11
FPS: 10
FPS: 10
FPS: 8
FPS: 8
```

This slowdown happens also if I do not show the image or if I only call `cap.grab()` and not `cap.retrieve( ... )`.

What am I doing wrong? How can I fix that? What could cause this slowdown? Do I have to free some resources or call some bookkeeping function with OpenCV?

**UPDATE:**

- memory usage seems constant (using `top`).
- `ipcs` shows no changes also.

Comment: Check the video compression codec and also it's likely that all is done in software only due to lack of gpu support.

Comment: I do not think you should display the image for the test. That takes time as well and it will give false values in your measurements.

Comment: The slowdowns happens also if I do not display the image. Additionally, I want the image on screen, without the slowdown ;)

Comment: What is your OpenCV version?

Comment: can you observe memory usage? There are some reports about memory leaks. What kind of opencv version are you using and which OS?

Comment: @Micka I was just about to ask about memory usage.

Comment: OS Linux Debian testing, OpenCV 4.2.0. I extended my question.

Comment: Check that the problem also appear on video files. If a webcam us used for the input, be aware that many webcams use slow filters (eg. median filter to remove the noise or an automatic constrast/luminosity regulation) and/or energy/througput saving algorithms.